# How can I do an suggestion for an automatic import package in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

if I write the follow row:

```
public class CellActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener;
```

I receive an eclipse warning that the interface is unknown. When I work on the university  computer, there in eclipse I receive suggestion for import package, but I don't receive it on the home computer. How can I receive these suggestions on home computer? Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the interface exists on the classpath of your project on your home computer?

Comment: Hi Gary, as I wrote, finally I copied the eclipse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> next to class name for which you need suggestion. Or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports. Also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I think I tried it, but it didn't work. At finally I copied eclipse library from class to home computer.

Answer (score 0):

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> when the cursor located at the warning line, then pick an operation (to import class)from the popup memnu.

Comment: Hi Chance, thanks. As I answered to Harry Joy, I copied the right-working eclipse to home computer.